# Error creando trigger en oracle: Error(36,21): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement ORACLE 11G

Tags: oracle-11g

Tenía un trigger , el cual estaba funcionando bien, sin embargo tuve que hacerle unas modificaciones y entre ellas necesito el if que tiene el comentario de " --VALIDAR ESTADO DE ORDEN DE COMPRA PRIMERO"  sin embargo me dice que hay un error: Error(36,21): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement.  Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal??

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PAZKO.APROBARORDEN
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON PAZKO.APROBACION_DETALLE
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE ACEPTADAS INT;
    RECHAZADAS INT;
    ESTADO VARCHAR2(50);
    CANTIDAD INT;
    APROBACION VARCHAR2(200);
    IDENTIDAD VARCHAR2(150);
    USUARIOO VARCHAR2(2000);
    TIPO VARCHAR2(200);
    ESTADOOC PAZKO.ORDEN_COMPRA.ESTADO%TYPE;
    ESTADOSC PAZKO.SOLICITUD_OC.ESTADO%TYPE;
    BEGIN
    ESTADO:=:NEW.ESTADO;
    APROBACION:=:NEW.APROBACION;
    IDENTIDAD:=:NEW.IDENTIDAD;
      IF UPDATING(ESTADO) THEN
      
           --VALIDAR ESTADO DE ORDEN DE COMPRA PRIMERO
            IF TIPO='Orden de compra' THEN
                SELECT ESTADO into ESTADOOC FROM PAZKO.ORDEN_COMPRA  WHERE ORDEN_COMPRA=APROBACION;
            ELSE
                SELECT ESTADO into ESTADOSC FROM PAZKO.SOLICITUD_OC  WHERE SOLICITUD_OC=APROBACION;
            END IF;
            
            IF ((ESTADOOC='E' OR ESTADOOC='Z') OR (ESTADOSC='E' OR ESTADOSC='Z')) THEN----IF  EDD
                    SELECT 'YA ESTA ACEPTADA O RECHAZADA' FROM DUAL;
            ELSE
                --ACEPTADOS
                IF ESTADO='Aceptado' THEN
    
                     SELECT NVL(( SELECT  MAX(A.CANTIDAD) 
                   FROM PAZKO.APROBACION A WHERE A.ID=IDENTIDAD AND ROWNUM=1 ),0) INTO CANTIDAD FROM DUAL;
    
                  SELECT  CAST((NVL((SELECT COUNT(AD.APROBACION) 
                   FROM PAZKO.APROBACION_DETALLE AD JOIN PAZKO.APROBACION A
                   ON A.ID=AD.IDENTIDAD AND AD.ESTADO='Aceptado'),0)) AS INT) INTO ACEPTADAS FROM DUAL;
                   
                   SELECT CAST((NVL((SELECT COUNT(AD.APROBACION) 
                   FROM PAZKO.APROBACION_DETALLE AD JOIN PAZKO.APROBACION A
                   ON A.ID=AD.IDENTIDAD AND AD.ESTADO='Rechazado'),0)) AS INT) INTO RECHAZADAS FROM DUAL;
                   
                    IF RECHAZADAS>0 THEN --IF R
                     UPDATE PAZKO.APROBACION_DETALLE SET ESTADO='Pendiente' WHERE APROBACION=APROBACION;
                     ELSE
                    IF (ACEPTADAS >=CANTIDAD) THEN --IF ACC
                       SELECT  ENTIDAD INTO TIPO FROM PAZKO.APROBACION WHERE ID=IDENTIDAD AND ROWNUM=1;
                       IF TIPO='Orden de compra'  THEN--IF4
                         UPDATE PAZKO.ORDEN_COMPRA 
                         SET USUARIO='SOFTLAND MOBILE',USUARIO_CONFIRMA='SOFTLAND MOBILE',
                         ESTADO='E'
                         WHERE ORDEN_COMPRA=APROBACION;
                       ELSE--ELSE IF4
                         UPDATE PAZKO.SOLICITUD_OC 
                         SET USUARIO='SOFTLAND MOBILE',USUARIO_CANCELA='SOFTLAND MOBILE',
                         ESTADO='E'
                         WHERE SOLICITUD_OC=APROBACION;
                      END IF;
                    END IF;--IF ACC
                    END IF;--IF R
                END IF;
    
    
    
                 --RECHAZADOS
                IF ESTADO='Rechazado' THEN 
                     SELECT NVL(( SELECT  MAX(A.CANTIDAD) 
                   FROM PAZKO.APROBACION A WHERE A.ID=IDENTIDAD AND ROWNUM=1),0) INTO CANTIDAD FROM DUAL;
    
                   SELECT CAST((NVL((SELECT COUNT(AD.APROBACION) 
                   FROM PAZKO.APROBACION_DETALLE AD JOIN PAZKO.APROBACION A
                   ON A.ID=AD.IDENTIDAD AND AD.ESTADO='Rechazado'),0)) AS INT) INTO RECHAZADAS FROM DUAL;
                   
                    SELECT  CAST((NVL((SELECT COUNT(AD.APROBACION) 
                   FROM PAZKO.APROBACION_DETALLE AD JOIN PAZKO.APROBACION A
                   ON A.ID=AD.IDENTIDAD AND AD.ESTADO='Aceptado'),0)) AS INT) INTO ACEPTADAS FROM DUAL;
                   
                   
                    IF ACEPTADAS>0 THEN --IF A
                     UPDATE PAZKO.APROBACION_DETALLE SET ESTADO='Pendiente' WHERE APROBACION=APROBACION;
                     ELSE
                   IF (RECHAZADAS >=CANTIDAD) THEN  --IF RCC
    
                   SELECT  ENTIDAD INTO TIPO FROM PAZKO.APROBACION WHERE ID=IDENTIDAD AND ROWNUM=1;
    
                    IF TIPO='Orden de compra' THEN--IF6
                     UPDATE PAZKO.ORDEN_COMPRA 
                     SET USUARIO='SOFTLAND MOBILE',USUARIO_CONFIRMA='SOFTLAND MOBILE',
                     ESTADO='Z'
                     WHERE ORDEN_COMPRA=APROBACION;
                    ELSE--ELSE IF6
                     UPDATE PAZKO.SOLICITUD_OC 
                     SET USUARIO='SOFTLAND MOBILE',USUARIO_CANCELA='SOFTLAND MOBILE',
                     ESTADO='Z'
                     WHERE SOLICITUD_OC=APROBACION;
                   END IF;
                 END IF;--IF RCC
                 END IF;-- IF A
               END IF;
    
    
            END IF;--IF EDD
      END IF;
    
    END;
```

Comment: Justamente lo que te indica el mensaje de error: te falta el `INTO` en `SELECT 'YA ESTA ACEPTADA O RECHAZADA' FROM DUAL`.

Comment: Efectivamente. Quiere decir que en oracle cuando se usa into en un select en todos los demás hay que usar el into??? Esto es así en todas las versiones de oracle??  En sql server no es necesaro usar into en todos los select!!!

Comment: Mejor dicho, cuando hacés un `select` (en este caso, en un trigger) necesitás asignar lo retornado en una variable (podrías crear nada más una variable auxiliar para ello). Ten en cuenta además que un trigger en Oracle es [una unidad PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS2001). Cada SGBD tiene su particularidad :)